# Вывести количество элементов первого массива, которых нет во втором

Tags: c++, массивы, инспекция-кода

> Дано два массива `x` и `y` разного размера. Найти количество элементов первого массива, которых нет во втором.

Вот основная часть кода. Размер первого массива `x` - `cnt`, второго `y` - `cnt1`.
Прошу покритиковать, потому что не особо нравится, как решил.

```
int count = 0;
bool flag;

for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    flag = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < cnt1; j++) {
        if (x[i] == y[j]) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) 
        count++;
}
cout << " count : " << count << endl;
```

Comment: Флаг - это не очень и он тут лишний. Лучше count инкрементировать при равенстве значений )

Comment: Подправил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все эти флаги, транспаранты, плакатики только мелькают перед глазами. Так же хорошечно:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cnt1; j++) {
        if (x[i] == y[j]) {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
} 
count = cnt - count;
cout << " count : " << count << endl;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88290/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-chernin-----).